# Ansible replace playbook

Tags: replace, ansible

I have recentry started learning ansible and now i have one qiestion:

here is my playbook:

```
    ---
- name: execute command with sudo
  hosts: all
  user: root
  become: yes
  tasks:
     - name: executing
       command: sed -i "s/print_thresholds($name,undef,undef,92,98);/#print_thresholds($name,undef,undef,92,98);/g" /etc/munin/plugins/df
```

it was worked fine, sed replaced me all what i need, but i got this alert.

> [WARNING]: Consider using the replace, lineinfile or template module
>   rather than running sed.  If you need to use command because replace,
>   lineinfile or template is insufficient you can add warn=False to this
>   command task or set command_warnings=False in ansible.cfg to get rid
>   of this message.

so, can you tell me please correct playbook?

Comment: Everything we can advise you is to read the warning and use any of the methods listed there.

Comment: listed where? Can you  give me link to methods?

Comment: In the warning message you added yourself to the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first of all read about the [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) module as the warning suggest.

Then, although your code and the use of sed is correct, it is not the safest way to use Ansible to edit a file, mainly because it is not idempotent and as error-resistant as using an Ansible module.

This code produces the same (in some cases better) result as the sed command but using the lineinfile module:

```
- name: executing
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/munin/plugins/df
    regexp: 'print_thresholds($name,undef,undef,92,98)'
    line: '^#print_thresholds($name,undef,undef,92,98)'
```